# MVC 3 Razor, don't show default value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.field) which works fine, however it defaults to 0 for numbers, and to N/A for strings if they are not set, how can i possible change that such it doesn't show anything if the value is not set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make the values in your model nullable, like so:

```
public class Model
{
    public int? Field { get; set; }
}
```

That way an empty value will map to the null value and vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

Change your model so it has nullable properties:

```
class YourModel {
    [Required]
    public int? Integer { get; set; }
}
```